# Android Unit Tests and Global Static Variables

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, static-members

I have a big application having lots of classes with static variables.
I added a couple of unit tests to project.
Now every test I run does system initialize all static variables?

If yes : How can I prevent it?

If No : Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static variables gets initialized while class loads, you can not stop and you should not.

If you don't want this behavior, they should be declared as instance members instead of class level members.